# Как обработать тело исключения на asp net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Хочу получать только то, что я передаю в теле исключения, а не все исключения.
Пример передачи сообщения исключения

```
if (!result.Succeeded)
{
    throw new ServerException("Invalid password");
}
```

В результате получаю

```
Store.Shared.Common.Exceptions.ServerException: Invalid password
   at Store.BusinessLogicLayer.Services.AccountService.SignInAsync(LoginModel model) in D:\Store\Store.BusinessLogicLayer\Services\AccountService.cs:line 137
   at Store.PresentationLayer.Controllers.AccountController.SignInAsync(LoginModel model) in D:\Store\Store.PresentationLayer\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 32
```

Код ServerExeption

```
public class ServerException : Exception
{
    public Errors Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ServerException(string description, Errors errorCode = Errors.InternalServerError) : base(description)
    {
        Code = errorCode;
        Description = description;
    }
}
```

Как получать только invalid password?

Comment: можно ошибку залогировать, а на клиент отправить просто текст

Comment: @Anton Nikolaev А я думал можно как то пропарсить строку и и получить только то что я пишу или может как то в мидлвере обработать

Comment: @Alexander Petrov  исключение получаю в сервисе

Comment: Слой бизнес логики

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Вы это имели ввиду?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Вы говорили можно как то в мидлвере это сделать, не подскажете как

Comment: "В результате получаю" - где получаете?

Comment: "Хочу получать только то, что я передаю в теле исключения, а не все исключения." Перевожу вашу фразу: "Хочу получить только свойство Message исключения, а не StackTrace"

Comment: @4per именно так и есть, простите сначала не знал как правильно написать